# Waiting List for PhD in Math Question

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I’m in a masters in applied math program at a university and I applied for the PhD entry but didn’t get it for this upcoming fall. However, I got an email from the director saying the department would like to consider me for Spring and that their all out of funding for Fall and they would like to see one more semester of grades to revaluate for Spring 2022 (got a B in 1 out of 3 classes this first semester).

So I had them roll over my application for the Spring. I really like this program but I’m unsure of how likely I am to be admitted even if I do well considering I’m on a waiting list. What do you guys think?

Comment: This is very strange. Is this program in the United States?

Answer (score 4):

The most anyone can say is that the better you do, the better your chances. But in general, I'd suggest that you look for other options as they don't seem, from what you say, to be pursuing you. Cast a wide net.

Answer (score 1):

You're not admitted until you receive the admit decision letter. As such, it would be foolhardy to not prepare a plan B. What that plan B should be is up to you, but come up with some plan such that if you are not accepted by the program in Spring, you still have something else to do with minimal downtime.